# How can I use CloudWatch to see detailed monitoring for EC2 instances from Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-ec2, monitoring, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I could do this from the AWS Console and from the command line :

aws ec2 monitor-instances --region  --instance-ids

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-monitoring

I could use the above Monitoring API, however this needs to be done for Existing EC2 Instances.

Comment: Are the "Existing EC2 Instances" are managed by CloudFormation?

Comment: You can enable it through the ec2 console, or you can do this process https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-get-template.html I have had mixed results with cloudformation modifications. Depending on the service I would suggest tearing down, making the change and restarting

Comment: @LaurentJalbertSimard EC2 Instances need to be monitored through Cloudwatch

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an **AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm** type with any supported metrics for EC2 instances.

For example, assume you need to monitor CPU utilization.

```
"CPUAlarm" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
  "Properties" : {
    "AlarmDescription" : "CPU alarm for my instance",
    "AlarmActions" : [ { "Ref" : "logical name of an AWS::SNS::Topic resource" } ],
    "MetricName" : "CPUUtilization",
    "Namespace" : "AWS/EC2",
    "Statistic" : "Average",
    "Period" : "60",
    "EvaluationPeriods" : "3",
    "Threshold" : "90",
    "ComparisonOperator" : "GreaterThanThreshold",
    "Dimensions" : [ {
      "Name" : "InstanceId",
      "Value" : { "Ref" : "logical name of an AWS::EC2::Instance resource" }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Ref - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-cloudwatch.html

Comment: I am actually looking for detailed monitoring..  
[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch-new.html] 
May be something like below, but the code dosen't work  
[http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/ec2-example-managing-instances.html#monitor-and-unmonitor-instances]

Comment: Well, in that case, Add properties **Monitoring** if you are using EC2 instances and **InstanceMonitoring** for AutoScaling Groups. I'll tag the reference AWS docs below for syntax info for you.

Monitoring Ref - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-launchtemplate-monitoring.html

InstanceMonitoring - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html#cfn-as-launchconfig-instancemonitoring

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use it in the script to enable and see the detailed monitoring for existing EC2 Instances

Comment: 'Ec2Instance: 
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    Properties: 
     "ImageId" : ami-xxxxxxx,
        "Monitoring" : "true" '

Comment: Update the CF template you used to create the stack with the monitoring parameter.

However, I don't think one can add detailed monitoring to a running instance on the fly via cloud formation.

Comment: may be using python in lambda ?

Comment: Yeah, that might work. 

But again, if your instances are EBS back-end, the hassle-free way would be to just spin up the instances again with detailed monitoring.